# Button suddenly responds to touch up outside, not touch up inside

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

My iPhone application has just suddenly changed behavior and I have no idea why. I have a small button and it is now only firing on touch up outside and not touch up inside. I'm not aware of anything I changed that may have caused this.

As you can see from the image below, it is correctly wired for touch up inside to the onAdd selector.

[image]

Any ideas on what could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check GestureRecognizers, other IBActions in this view. Try to link up event with touchUpOutside and check is it working ok, then revert to Inside and check behaviour. Use NSLog in methods to see what's firing on tap. Without sample code I can't say much more.

Comment: You were right, I'd added another IBAction that played with my original IBAction.